# Android Removed Views are not garbage collected

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm battling with memory issues so I came up with a small test app to try to understand more on how the VM is handling garbage collection.
The following code is very simple.

1. The Activity is made of only one LinearLayout
2. Every seconds, a timer calls a Method which 1) remove all children from the LinearLayout 2) adds 3000 new TextViews to the layout.

Using DDMS, I can see that the number of objects instantiated keeps rising and that the children that have been removed from the LinearLayout never get collected.
Why is that?

```
namespace MemoryTests
{
    [Activity(Label = "MemoryTests", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        private Timer _timer = new Timer();

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Elapsed += AddTextViews;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        public void AddTextViews(object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                              {
                                  var layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout);
                                  layout.RemoveAllViews();
                                  for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
                                  {
                                      TextView tx = new TextView(ApplicationContext);
                                      layout.AddView(tx);
                                  }
                              });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never call `Invalidate()` on `layout`, try that and see if that helps.

Comment: As long as you don't reference the `TextView` instances elsewhere, they should be marked for garbage collection and be collected eventually.

Comment: Hey Cheesey! I see you also lurk in StackOverflow on top of the Xamarin forum. Invalidate() did the trick. Thanks... again.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the problem with the code in this particular case is that you do not call `Invalidate()` on `layout`. This means that `layout`, even though you have called `RemoveAllViews()` on it, did not redraw and still thinks it has all those `TextView` instances from before in it.

So when you call `Invalidate()` it redraws itself with the new `TextView` instances and forgets everything about the old ones. Now they are ready to be garbage collected as long as nothing else reference them.

Comment: Brilliant answer. For the future readers: if the View has a background set with a Drawable, it's important to call BackGround.SetCallback(null) to ensure it will be collected